# PayPal Digital Goods and Showing Purchases

Tags: php, paypal, ownership, accounts, paypal-digital-goods

I am developing a website for a client who wants to sell his stock photos. I'm trying to get Paypal Digital Goods to work for a little while and have been having no luck at all. If anyone could point me toward a good tutorial on getting that to work that would be great as well.

After that another thing I need to get working is being able to show the people who purchased these items that they have it in their account. I was thinking of going Boolean values saying if they own each individual item, but that would end up being quite repetative so I wanted to know if there was a better way?

I already have the user system set up, I'm just stuck after this.

Comment: Can you clarify what the exact problem is you're having with Digital Goods?

Answer (score 0):

You can check http://www.ktools.net and Photostore (maybe it is cheaper to buy this app then to build a new one from the ground)

In case you decide to go with your own solution, tracking purchases can be done via separate table inside database

For example "purchases" with the next fields

> id INT,   userId INT,  purchasedItem INT,  purchaseDate datetime, 
>   expire datetime

The last field is optional so you can set expire when the download won't be available for this user (for example you can set up 48hrs for download)

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm gonna try to stick with my own solution. I'll definitely use that table system the only problem I'm still stuck on is how I can get PayPal digital goods to work. If you have anything for that it would be greatly appreciated!